# How do I get sound to work on my iMac G5 running Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: macosx

When I click the sound icon I only have a dummy output device there.

I have a G5 iMac I think model 8,7. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 for powerpc64

Thanks

Comment: I tried following the advice on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules but this is what I get in the terminal:


root@mycomputer:/home/myuser# apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-31-powerpc64-smp
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-31-powerpc64-smp'
root@myuser-desktop:/home/myuser#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I finally found this one command that did the trick and the sound is crystal clear after rebooting. Here's what I entered in the Terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local.conf
```

Just reboot and it all works perfectly. I found the fix at [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Why_do_I_have_no_sound.3F).